# Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch from editor to console in Spyder?

Tags: ipython, spyder

I'm using Spyder via Anaconda on a Mac, and often switch back and forth between the editor and console. I was wondering if there's a keyboard shortcut to switch quickly between these two panes. It's just not quite convenient to do it with the trackpad or mouse.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. IPython console to Editor: <kbd>Command</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
2. Editor to IPython console: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

(On windows you can replace <kbd>Command</kbd> with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>)